# what is the Jconnect version compatible with java-11

Tags: java, sybase, java-11

For my application to connect with Sybase database

I am using :

- java version: java-11
- jdbc driver: ojdbc11-21.3.0.0
- Jconnect driver: Jconn2_5.5

but getting the error

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:sybase:Tds

What is the latest version of jconnect driver compatible with java 11?

Comment: What you specify as "jdbc driver" seems to be the Oracle JDBC driver, which is not relevant if you want to connect to Sybase.

Comment: BTW, it looks like your URL is wrong, the format for Sybase is jdbc:sybase:Tds:<host>:<port> , the error suggests you only specified `jdbc:sybase:Tds`.